# How to update data binding in jquery code using angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using emojiarea jquery plugin in my angular project. everything works fine but I want to update emojiarea text to an angular public variable. how should I do it? I tried to use zone.js but I did not get success.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#example').emojioneArea({
      autoHideFilters: true,
      saveEmojisAs: 'unicode',
      events: {
        keyup: function (editor, e) {
          this.message = this.getText();
          this.zone.run(() => this.onPlayerStateChange(e));
          this.chRef.detectChanges();
          console.log(this.message);
        }
      }
    });
 }
```

I want to get the value of this.message variable inside submit function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let that = this;
    $('#example').emojioneArea({
      autoHideFilters: true,
      saveEmojisAs: 'unicode',
      events: {
        keyup: function (editor, e) {
          that.message = that.getText();
          that.zone.run(() => that.onPlayerStateChange(e));
          that.chRef.detectChanges();
          console.log(that.message);
        }
      }
    });
 }
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

as i figured out this.getText(); returns current text from emojioneArea, and this.message is angulars variable so you should save reference to angular component so it hold this message variable, try write this

```
 let that = this;
    $('#example').emojioneArea({
      autoHideFilters: true,
      saveEmojisAs: 'unicode',
      events: {
        keyup: function (editor, e) {
          that.message = this.getText();
          that.zone.run(() => that.onPlayerStateChange(e));
          that.chRef.detectChanges();
          console.log(that.message);
        }
      }
    });
```